# How to acces ACF Relation Fields in JSON API

Tags: php, json, angularjs, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i'm a Wordpress fan and working the most time with the [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).
I have two Custom Post Types which are linked together with the [relationship field from the ACF Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/). I'm working currently on a mobile Version where i'm using the [Plugin JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). It works perfectly, instead the relation field values.

This i see in the JSON File with 1 linked resource:

```
["a:1:{i:0;s:3:"163";}", "a:1:{i:0;s:3:"163";}"]
```

and this for 2 linked resources:

```
["a:2:{i:0;s:3:"261";i:1;s:2:"56";}", "a:2:{i:0;s:3:"261";i:1;s:2:"56";}"]
```

### UPDATE

This is a piece from the JSON File. The related fields are "Speakers" with the ugly ID's in it. Thats what I get from JSON API from Wordpress.

```
"custom_fields": {
            "main_statement": [
                "",
                ""
            ],
            "type_of_presentation": [
                "keynote",
                "keynote"
            ],
            "room": [
                "no_room",
                "no_room"
            ],
            "skill_level": [
                "null",
                "null"
            ],
            "start_date": [
                "1412084700",
                "1412084700"
            ],
            "end_date": [
                "1412087700",
                "1412087700"
            ],
            "speakers": [
                "a:1:{i:0;s:3:\"154\";}",
                "a:1:{i:0;s:3:\"154\";}"
            ]
        }
```

Do you have any clue how i can get the ID's out of this messy thing, so that I can search for the ID's in the whole JSON Object to display the related posts?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards

Comment: data shown is not valid JSON , hard to help with invalid data

Comment: hey @charlietfl I copied the some code from the JSON, hope it helps.

Comment: `speakers` data is php serilaized arrays,  `json_decode()` them first

Answer (score 1):

"Speakers" data is a php **serialized array**.
So you basically just need to use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unserialize.php) php function.
I tested it and it, indeed, extract the IDs in arrays

*json_decode() won't work on non-JSON data.*

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would highly suggest moving to [WP REST API v2](http://v2.wp-api.org/), which is the API that is eventually going to be included in the WordPress core.

To answer your question, the problem is that the JSON API -plugin that you are using is showing the data exactly as it is stored in the MySQL database. In order for PHP objects to be stored into the database they have to be serialized. `a:1:{i:0;s:3:\"154\";}` is a serialized representation of a PHP array `array("154")`.

What we need to do is to apply [maybe_unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) on every custom field value in the response. Luckily the JSON API -plugin author has included a `json_api_import_wp_post` action in the plugin that is run right after the response post object has been formed. You can add the code snippet below to your theme's functions.php or a custom plugin (if you have one for the project).

```
/**
 * Apply maybe_unserialize on all post's custom_fields in a JSON API response.
 *
 * @param JSON_API_Post $api_post The result of JSON_API_Post->import_wp_object
 * @param WP_Post $wp_post WP_Post that was converted
 * @return JSON_API_Post
 */
function namespace_unserialize_json_api_import_wp_post($api_post, $wp_post) {
  // Check if there are custom_fields
  if( isset($api_post->custom_fields) ) {
    // Loop them all through
    foreach($api_post->custom_fields as $key => $custom_field) {
      // All of the custom_field values are arrays, so apply maybe_unserialize
      // to all the array items with maybe_unserialize and set it as the key
      $api_post->custom_fields->$key = array_map('maybe_unserialize', $custom_field);
    }
  }
  return $api_post;
}
// Add namespace_unserialize_json_api_import_wp_post to the json_api_import_wp_post action hook.
add_action('json_api_import_wp_post', 'namespace_unserialize_json_api_import_wp_post', 10, 2);
```

Note: Replace "namespace_" with something more suitable for your project.